# How to get .isalpha to not count accent letters?

Tags: python

My code is:

def return_num_characters(s):
count = 0
for i in s:
if i.isalpha():
count+=1
return count

Overestimates number of alpha english characters in a input string (less spaces, punctuation, numbers, and all other characters not a-z)

How do I get it to return properly?  Output is 994 when it should be 974 for the below test case

Test case is : case_character_count
Wie schön bist du,
Freundliche Stille, himmlische Ruh! -
Sehet, wie die klaren Sterne
Wandeln in des Himmels [Aun]1,
Und auf uns [herniederschaun]2,
Schweigend aus der blauen Ferne.

Wie schön bist du,
Freundliche Stille, himmlische Ruh! -
Schweigend naht des Lenzes Milde
Sich der Erde weichem Schooß,
Kränzt den Silberquell mit Moos,
Und mit Blumen die Gefilde.

Wie schön bist du,
Freundliche Stille, himmlische Ruh! -
Wenn nicht mehr des Wetters Wogen
Um den Himmel tobend ziehn,
Donner krachen, Blitze sprühn,
Blüht des Friedens stiller Bogen.

Wie schön bist du,
Freundliche Stille, himmlische Ruh! -
Wo der Wellen rauh Getümmel
Schweigt, des Meeres Brausen ruht,
In der unbewegten Fluth
Glänzt der klare, blaue Himmel.

Wie schön bist du,
Freundliche Stille, himmlische Ruh! -
Nicht zu Salems hohen Thoren,
Zu der Königsstädte Pracht
Stieg die heil'ge Wundernacht,
Aus des Urlichts Quell gebohren.

Wie schön bist du,
Freundliche Stille, himmlische Ruh! -
Engelchöre sangen Lieder
In des Nachthauchs leisem Wehn,
Und auf Bethlehms stille Höhn
Schwebten Seraphim hernieder. -

Wie schön bist du,
Freundliche Stille, himmlische Ruh! -
In des Kindes zarter Hülle,
In der heil'gen Mutter Schooß,
Auf der Krippe weichem Moos
Lag des ew'gen Lichtes Fülle!

Answer (score 2):

Use `i.isascii() and i.isalpha()` in place of just `i.isalpha()`.